# Google Calendar return the result to Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-calendar

Is it possible to get the selected event's result to Activity using Google calendar?
I'm using `startActivityForResult` to open the google calendar from my application, I would like get the selected event's details in my application on `onActivityForResult` method. Is it possible to override the select event in google calendar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Calendar API to find and view public calendar events.
The Calendar API lets you display, create and modify calendar events as well as work with many other calendar-related objects, such as calendars or access controls.

GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events

```
 import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
 import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;

 // ...

 // Initialize Calendar service with valid OAuth credentials
 Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials)
.setApplicationName("applicationName").build();

// Retrieve an event
Event event = service.events().get('primary', "eventId").execute();

System.out.println(event.getSummary());
```

I believe you might find Google Calendar API really useful.

Reference Link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events

This might be help you.Good Luck

Comment: I can able to display the calendar. But what i need is, how to navigate back to my application, when user selects the Event from calendar?

Comment: what you want to select the event first at google calendar and get the value at your application

Comment: I have one confusion that are you opening the calendar at your application or you are selecting the date from the google calendar plz clear that

Comment: i think @User7284 is using google calender API  is it wright ?

Comment: @ShubhankGupta Yes i'm opening Google calendar from my application using intent, calendar displays all the events, user clicks on any event from calendar, system should navigate back to my application, and i would like to display the event details in my app screen. is it possible to do? Intent im using for opening the application  `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, builder.build()); startActivityForResult(intent, 2);`